# Grouping Tray Icons

Tags: icons, system-tray, top-bar

Is there a setting/app/extension that will let me group my "tray icons" similar to how Windows does it?

I know a lot of folks like to keep background processes to a minimum, but there are quite a few things that I like to keep running to perform my daily tasks.

I'm afraid if I add a few more, the icons will start to encroach on the clock.

Ubuntu 20.04
[image: screenshot of tray icons]

Windows 10
[image: screen shot of widnwos 10 icons]

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 and I'm kind of a Linux newbie.

THANKS!

Comment: What is "similar to how Windows does it"?  Describe a bit. Not all users here (that includes me) have familiarity with Windows, either because they exclusively use Linux for many years, or perhaps use OSX as second OS.

Comment: Thanks, @vanadium for pointing that out. I've added a screenshot from a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the Gnome shell extension ['Tray Icons: Reloaded'](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/) by MartinPL. The extension has 'overflow' mode that groups tray icons if it is more than three.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @drpjkurian. It looks like it does exactly what I am asking for. I've installed it and it's not really functioning as I expected it to. But I'm sure it's just my lack of knowledge in getting it configured properly. 

I'll mark this one as answered and if need be and another question on configuring this extension if I can't figure it out in a few days 

Answer (score 2):

The Gnome shell extension [Tray Icons: Reloaded](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/) did not work when I tried downloading a numbered version and put it on the location `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` as specified by the developer on his/her [github repo](https://github.com/MartinPL/Tray-Icons-Reloaded)

Alternately what worked for my Ubuntu 20.04 is the following:

1. Install directly to shell from the [Tray Icons: Reloaded](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/)
   [image]
2. Next turn off the 'Ubuntu AppIndicators' from 'Extensions'
   [image] [image]
3. Now edit the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to uncomment:

   ```
   #WaylandEnable=false
   ```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

4. You might need a logout/re-login or a reboot.

Now the tray indicator worked!
[image]

Hope this helps anyone who needs it.

Also, if anyone can figure out how the versioned 'Tray Icons: Reloaded' works please do share. There might be some additional features available from them.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me to update and improve the answer. I provided some visuals with additional texts!

Comment: **Danger:** installing per-user extensions (placing at `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`) grants permanent access to whoever has the extension uuid registered on extensions.gnome.org now or in the future!